# Node.js - FireBas - Functions, TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i have a an error while i trying to my execute my function "sendNotification", i have searched answers in stackoverflow for similar problem and i didn't find it.

This is my current javascript code :

```js
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event => {

 const user_id = event.params.user_id;
 const notification = event.params.notification;

 console.log('The User Id is : ', user_id);
 });
```

This is my fonction in firebase :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqtEY.png)

This is my notification database looks like: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csNC5.png)

and this is my log :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U7vP.png)

Comment: Please post the code in here as text. It's hard to help you if you post images of code.

Comment: 'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event => {

 const user_id = event.params.user_id;
 const notification = event.params.notification;

 console.log('The User Id is : ', user_id);
 });

Comment: The signatures of Cloud Functions have changed. You'll need to update it by following this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: Thanks a lot @FrankvanPuffelen